# How to create a Data frame and prevent creation of new columns and additional rows during a for loop for each dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-docx

I'm new to posting here.

I'm currently trying to extract tables from a word document and have them laid out in a transposed data frame that can be exported as a csv.

My issue lies on the data frame I get from the following code:

```
from docx.api import Document
import pandas as pd

def extract_tables_from_docx(path,output_path,name):
    document = Document(path)
    data = []
    for table in document.tables:
        keys = tuple(cell.text for cell in table.rows[0].cells)
        for row in table.rows[1:]:
            data.append(dict(zip(keys,(cell.text for cell in row.cells))))
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data).T
    print(df1)
```

[This is the current data frame I get when I input the relevant information when calling the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfJ5b.png)

So the issue is that I'm adding extra columns to fill in the information for the next data set when I want the data to be filled where the NaN's are. Basically every new entry from the loop is causing the data to be entered to the right if that's how you describe it. I'm fairly new to Python so apologies if this code doesn't look good.

Can anyone help on how I get around this? Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

[This is how I expect my data frames to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXzNA.png)

[The dataset I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA06w.png)

Comment: Try using `data` as a `dictionary` instead of a `list`

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the data that produces your problem.  Specifically, what does the the variable text look like for row 0 and row 1.  While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, or data. Use text. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is organized "vertically" with the records in columns rather than rows. So you need something like this:

```
from docx.api import Document
import pandas as pd


def extract_tables_from_docx(path):
    document = Document(path)
    data = []

    for table in document.tables:
        keys = (cell.text for cell in table.columns[0].cells)
        values = (cell.text for cell in table.columns[1].cells)
        data.append(dict(zip(keys, values)))

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data).T
    print(df1)
```

Give that a try and see what you get.

Comment: I've reduced the additional code as suggested. I have also added an image of the result that I am expecting and the original dataset that I am using. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Jei I've updated my response based on the clearer view of what your inputs look like.

Comment: I've tried the following and it works. Only change I had to make is getting rid of the the transpose function since the data is now in the format that I need. Thank you, much appreciated!